# Calculator with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to coding with JavaScript(like 3 days) and I am trying to write a calculator with JavaScript and jQuery but I failed too much. If you can help me continue my Project
I can not display my result or any number in my input

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var result = 0;
  var previosNumber = 0;
  var currentNumber ='0';
  var operator = null;

  function updateDisplay(displayValue){
    var displayValue = displayValue.toString();
    $("#value-display").html(displayValue.substring(0,10));
  }

  updateDisplay(result);

  $("button").on("click",function(event){
    operator = $(this).html();
    console.log(operator);
  })

  $("#cancelBtn").on("click",function(event){
    result = 0;
    currentNumber = '0';
    updateDisplay(currentNumber);
  })

  $("#backSpaceBtn").on("click",function(event){
    currentNumber = currentNumber.substring(0,currentNumber.length-1)
    updateDisplay(currentNumber);
  })

  $(".btn.btn-dark").on("click",function(event){
    if(currentNumber === "0"){
      currentNumber = $(this).val();
    } else {
      currentNumber += $(this).val();
    }
    updateDisplay(currentNumber);
  })

  function operation(a,b,operator){
    a = parseFloat(a);
    b = parseFloat(b);
    console.log(a,b,operator);
    switch (operator) 
    {
      case "+":
        return a+b;
      case "-":
        return a-b;
      case "x":
        return a*b;
      case "/":
        return a/b;
      case "=":
        currentNumber = operation(previosNumber, currentNumber, operator);
        operator = null;
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Invalid operator");
    }
  }
})
```

this is my code.
I can't find my problem here

if you find my problem please let me know

I know that is not my only problem so if you find anything else please let me know

this is my html file

```
<body>
    <table>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1>Calculator
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-calculator-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                    <path d="M2 2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h8a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2zm2 .5v2a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h7a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-2a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-7a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5m0 4v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5M4.5 9a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5zM4 12.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5M7.5 6a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5zM7 9.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5m.5 2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5zM10 6.5v1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-1a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5m.5 2.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v4a.5.5 0 0 0 .5.5h1a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5v-4a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5z"/>
                </svg>
            </h1>
            
            <input type="text" aria-label="value" class="" id="value-display">
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Default button group">
            <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Vertical button group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id = "sumBtn" value="+">+</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id = "equalBtn" value="=">=</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id = "backSpaceBtn" value="Backspace">Backspace</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id = "cancelBtn"  value="Cancel">C</button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Vertical button group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id = "minusBtn" value="-">-</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn1" value="1">1</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn4" value="4">4</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn7" value="7">7</button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Vertical button group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id= "multiplicationBtn" value="x">x</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn2" value="2">2</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn5" value="5">5</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn8" value="8">8</button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group-vertical" role="group" aria-label="Vertical button group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id= "divideBtn" value="/">/</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn3" value="3">3</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn6" value="6">6</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn9" value="9">9</button>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="btn0" value="0">0</button>
        </div>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: this error was solved by changing the address of the JS file,what's the changes,  and I did't get the same problem with your code

Comment: You should do your exercise part by part. I feel like you wrote all the code and you are now like "a lot of stuff doesn't work probably". Go step by step, don't try to do all at once. Your error usually come from a misorder of loading script : but in your example, jquery is load as the first script, it should be ok. Another point, is not common to declare function as variable in javascript (you can do it, and sometimes, you have to), in your case `function operation(a,b,operator) { // your code }`. Declare your functions before using it (even if it can workds in JS)